# How to fix "DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique"?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan

I have a problem.. not sure why it gives me the mentioned error when calling "SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;" in line 4 of the code. Thanks for the help!

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is simplestorage a smart contract ? U probably can only store addresses of SimpleStorage contracts try -> .push(simpleSotrage.address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either define a `struct` under the contract like so with your needed variables so SimpleStorage can be defined.

```
contract StorageFactory {

    struct SimpleStorage{
        string name;
        uint data;
    }

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
}
```

Or it seems to me, that your imported `"./SimpleStorage.sol"` file might have the struct data needed so you can look into the SimpleStorage.sol file and copy the contract name, then in your main file do

```
contract StorageFactory is ContractName //Use the contract name you got in SimpleStorage.sol
```

This will allow it to get the struct data from the SimpleStorage.sol file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SimpleStorage.sol and look what's the name of contract.
Surely you will find that contract name in file (SimpleStorage.sol) will not be SimpleStorage.
Thatswhy you are not able to make array of type SimpleStorage[].